# Flutter IOS _CastError

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am currently developing a flutter app. I have tested a feature on Android and there everything worked, when I test it on IOS, unfortunately the following error is called:

```
_CastError (type 'Contract' is not a subtype of type 'Damage' in type cast)
```

The code to which the error refers is the following:

```
final Damage damage = item as Damage;
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    tooltip: 'Add',
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AddDocumentsPage(
            damage: damage,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  body: DocumentsList(
    attribute: 'date',
    documentable: item,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be very cautious when using the `as` keyword. It is very likely that your `item` isn't of type `Damage` and therefore cannot be cast into one.
Your best option here would be to create a new `Damage` object and fulfilling it with the data you need from `item`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This really helped me and now my code is working on all devices! :)